# Cygwin sshd and LDAP authentication

Tags: windows-xp, ldap, cygwin, ssh

Is it possible to configure sshd installed via cygwin on WinXP to use LDAP for user authentication? If so, where can I find a howto guide to do this?

Comment: An optimistic, but interesting question. Don't have an answer but LDAP authentication on Linux systems uses PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) and you could try to see if libpam_ldap comes with the Cygwin environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick tutorial for you.... [SSH CYGWIN Active Directory](http://www.joomlawebserver.com/freebsd/remote-access/05.-setting-up-ssh-on-cygwin-client-and-server.html)

Hope that helps..

Comment: thanks. going to see if this setup would work with other LDAP servers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have any suggestions for you about using the cygwin SSHD.  You might want to have a look at FreeSSHD and/or F-Secure SSH Server (I'm pretty sure F-Secure allows for LDAP authentication)...

Comment: I would but it took months to get cygwin certified for the servers, no way I could wait until they get around to test something else.